# Yield only if pattern match

Tags: scala, for-loop, pattern-matching, yield

I am building a list of different case class objects based on a loop and a pattern match. **I want to exclude (skip) the items hitting the default case** (essentially filtering the list, and mapping to types in one step).

I'm probably too new to Scala to see all the possibilities. My attempt:

```
    val events = for (ev <- data ) yield {

        ev.sport match {
            case "FOOTBALL" => new FootballEvent(ev)
            case "SOCCER" => new SoccerEvent(ev)
            case _ => None
        }

    }
```

I could filter the list afterwards, but I suspect there's some fancy Scala way of doing this :)

Please let me know if you have any idea of how this should best be done!

Comment: If there are only two cases, instead of three or more, this can be done in a single `for... yield` - here is an example: `for { Some(x) <- Some(None: Option[String]) } yield "should not get here"`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is not that it is yield syntax, but you can use collect with pattern matching:

```
val events = data.collect { ev => ev.sport match {
     case "FOOTBALL" => new FootballEvent(ev) 
     case "SOCCER"   => new SoccerEvent(ev)
}}
```

Unlike better known `.map` and `.foreach` it wont fail on "other" case and instead just drop unmatched items.

Comment: I'll leave you to it since you answered first, but neither of us quite got it right on the first try.  Okay, looks like you fixed the syntax error :)

Comment: did not notice collect b4.

Answer (score 11):

The standard filter in `for-yield` is obtained with `x <- y if f(x,..)`. Here is an example that uses a Partial Function.

```
val m: PartialFunction[Event, Event] = ev => ev.sport match {
  case "FOOTBALL" => new FootballEvent(ev)
  case "SOCCER" => new SoccerEvent(ev)
};

for { ev <- data if m.isDefindAt(ev)  
      val x = m(ev)
} yield x

// or, without the temporary binding:
for (ev <- data if m.isDefindAt(ev)) yield m(ev)
```

Note the similarity with [`Traversable.collect`](https://scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable)<sup>1</sup> mentioned in the other answer, which has this signature `def
collect[B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): CC[B]` and returns "a new collection resulting from applying the given partial function pf to each element on which it is defined and collecting the results".

An alternative without `if` is a variation of bwroga's deleted answer:

```
for { ev <- data;
      x <- ev.sport match {
        case "FOOTBALL" => Some(new FootballEvent(ev))
        case "SOCCER" => Some(new SoccerEvent(ev))
        case _ => None
      }
} yield x
```

This filters by subsequently iterating through None (i.e. "0 items") or Some (i.e. "1 item") after the initial map.

---

<sup>1</sup> If someone can tell me how to link to individual methods in the "new" scaladoc, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Link to the current scaladocs for `scala.collection.Traversable` http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Traversable.html